# Как передавать параметры в Route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

У меня есть Router с набором Route, и компонент который я хочу отобразить по этому пути

Мне нужно в `MyComponent` передать кастомные параметры, в данном случае допустим это будет `categoryName`.

Как я это делаю сейчас

```
function MyComponentWrap(props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) {
    return <MyComponent categoryName="ThisCategory" ...props />
}
```

Но мне не особенно нравится идея создания дополнительных компонентов враперов для этой цели, хочется передавать параметры напрямую.

И вроде как это можно сделать, смотрим тут - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32761932/6580397

Но я не понимаю как это можно сделать на TypeScript и можно ли вообще?

Вот определение `d.ts` `RouteComponentProps`

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<P> {
  match: match<P>;
  location: H.Location;
  history: H.History;
  staticContext?: any;
}
```

и сюда не входит `route`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приветствую!

В ореховой скорлупе все варианты доступа к RouteComponentProps выглядят так:

Если открыть https://codesandbox.io/s/206lkp662j ,и там открыть консоль, там на каждый из 6 рутов будет увидишь 6 логов в консоли. 5 из них содержат данные рута, и один нет.

Лично я бы советовал пользоваться withRoute или как декаратором или как элементом композиции, дабы наши контейнеры (так как именно контейнеры, а не компоненты, в идеале, должны знать про состояние) не зависили от уровня вложенности в рут или от чего то ещё.

```
const Component1 = props => {
  console.log(props);
  return '1';
}


const Component1WithRouter = withRouter(Component1);


const ComponentComposition = compose (
  withRouter,
  // any recompose  func or HOC goes here..
  // mySuperDataHoc
  // connect()
)(Component1)

@withRouter
class Component2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return '4';
  }
}


const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>


  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={Component1} />

      <Route path="/" render={params => {
          console.log(params);
          return '2';
        }} />

      <Route path="/">{params => {
        console.log(params);
          return '3';
      }}
      </Route>


      <Route path="/">
        <div>
          <Component1 /> {/* console.log -> empty! */}
        </div>
      </Route>

      <Route path="/">
        <div>
          <Component1WithRouter /> {/* console.log -> OK */}
        </div>
      </Route>

      <Route path="/" component={Component2} />



    </div>  
  </Router>    


  </div>
);
```

В консоли:

```
▶Object {match: Object, location: Object, history: Object}
▶Object {match: Object, location: Object, history: Object}
▶Object {match: Object, location: Object, history: Object}
Object {}
▶Object {match: Object, location: Object, history: Object}
▶Object {match: Object, location: Object, history: Object}
```

После уточнения, был предложен следующий вариант решения задачи:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';


// эти то что мы задаём сами вручную когда вызываем компонент
type OwnProps = {
  title: string;
}


// это всё вместе, что приедет в компонент в результате
type Props = OwnProps & RouteComponentProps<any> & {
  dispatch: Dispatch<any>
}


export default compose<Props, OwnProps>(
  withRouter,
  // connect() - подключаем редакс!
)(props => {

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Title: { props.title }</div>
      <div>Route: { props.match.url}</div>
      <div>{}
    </div>
  );

})
```

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api

Comment: я добавил 7й вариант по ссылке

Comment: и если надо могу написать где и как правильно добавить информацию о типах

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но насколько я понял это не то что я спрашивал, я хочу передать дополнительные, кастомные свойства, например "myProp" = "hallow", не match, location и history. В примере выше я передаю `categoryName="ThisCategory"`

Comment: Кроме того меня интересует TypeScript, как раз про withRouter мне интересно, но именно в контексте TypeScript, так как в последнем  версии тайпингов мой старый код с withRouter перестал работать.

Comment: Я не до конца понял, но кажется понял. Вот я добавил файл ComposedComponent, там используются OwnProps/WrappedProps. Соответственно в компонент мы сами передаём OwnProps, хотя внутри компонента распоряжаемся WrappedProps. Те пропсы, которых нет в OwnProps приезжают из подключенных hoc (типа withRouter и т.д.) Hoc может быть много, включая редакс connect(), всякие рест-запросы , авторизации и тд и тд

https://codesandbox.io/s/206lkp662j

Comment: ого, очень интересно, как вы объединили типы, даже не знал про такое, и про compose не знал, буду изучать

Comment: а что такое Hoc?

Comment: да, похоже это полностью решает мой вопрос, оказывается компонент можно чайлдом в Route закидывать, и понял как кастомные пропсы передавать.

Comment: В ответ хорошо бы код вынести который именно этому вопросу касается.

Comment: Приветствую! HOC это higher order component, к примеру MyComponentWrap из вашего вопроса. HOC получается компонент и опционально некоторые параметры и возвращает компонент с некими доп пропсами или совсем другой компонент (скажем спиннер-лоадер или что угодно. recompose - очень удобная библиотека, вот ссылка на апи. В общем-то она заточена на использование функциональных компонентов (которые stateless), но не толко. насчёт функции compose хочу уточнить, что лично у меня нормально работать получилось только с вариантом из recompose, а не из redux и пр, там я не понял с типами

Comment: вот про hoc https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html , на русском тоже должно быть много материалов. кстати на react-training.com выложены бесплатно крутые материалы по реакту, не знаю, временно ли это или навсегда

Comment: https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md

Comment: https://courses.reacttraining.com/p/advanced-react-free

Comment: ну и напоследок добавлю, что тип withRouter описан очень хорошо: `export function withRouter<P extends RouteComponentProps<any>>(component: React.ComponentType<P>): React.ComponentClass<Omit<P, keyof RouteComponentProps<any>>>;
` , то есть если использовать его как декоратор, результирующий компонент не будет иметь history, location, match пропсов, таким образом мы сможем его нормально использоваться. Раньше надо было их делать опциональными

Comment: там начало курса, и предложение купить полный курс, хотя может и бесплатная часть кому будет полезна, сейчас попробую с withRouter у себя разобраться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71011/discussion-between---and-daniel-khoroshko).

Answer (score 0):

Из 4 версии `React Router` убрали свойство route из параметров передающихся в контрол, поэтому код по ссылке в вопросе больше не работает и сделать так нельзя.

Решение - передавать свойства через встроенную конструкцию:

```
<Route path="comments" component={ (props: RouteComponentProps) => 
         <Comments myProp="value" ...props /> }/>
```